# GitLab unable to run my image on my server

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, devops, pipeline

I use Gitlab CI/CD. I run different `stage`on my pipeline.

For the `deploy-staging` i have a problem when my pipeline want run my image on my serve -->

```
$ ssh deployer@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker stop ${IMAGE_TAG}" || true
"docker stop" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker stop --help'.
Usage:  docker stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
Stop one or more running containers
$ ssh deployer@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker rm ${IMAGE_TAG}" || true
"docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rm --help'.
Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
Remove one or more containers
$ ssh deployer@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker rmi -f ${IMAGE_NAME}" || true
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rmi --help'.
Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]
Remove one or more images
$ ssh deployer@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker run --publish=8888:8888 -d ${IMAGE_NAME}"
"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker run --help'.
Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
Run a command in a new container
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/name=systemd': Operation not permitted
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

***yaml file :***

```
cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    paths:
        - .maven/

image: maven:3-jdk-8

stages:
    - build
    - test
    - analyze
    - package
    - release
    - deploy

before_script:
    - chmod +x mvnw
    - export MAVEN_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.maven
    - chmod +x mvnw
    - ./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:install-node-and-npm -DnodeVersion=v10.13.0 -DnpmVersion=6.4.1 -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME
    - ./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:npm -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME

maven-compile:
    stage: build
    script:
        - ./mvnw clean compile -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - target/classes/
            - target/generated-sources/
        expire_in: 1 day

#maven-test:
#    stage: test
#    script:
#        - ./mvnw test -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME
#    artifacts:
#        reports:
#            junit: target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
#        paths:
#            - target/test-results
#        expire_in: 1 day

#frontend-test:
#    stage: test
#    script:
#        - ./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:npm -Dfrontend.npm.arguments='test -- -u' -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME
#    artifacts:
#        reports:
#            junit: target/test-results/jest/TESTS-*.xml
#        paths:
#            - target/test-results
#        expire_in: 1 day

maven-package:
    stage: package
    script:
        - ./mvnw verify -Pprod -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - target/*.war
        expire_in: 1 day
docker-push:
    image: docker:latest
    services:
        - docker:dind
    variables:
        REGISTRY_URL: registry.gitlab.com
        DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
        DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
        IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
        IMAGE_TAG: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    stage: release
    dependencies:
        - maven-package
    before_script:
        - docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_BUILD_TOKEN" $REGISTRY_URL
    script:
        - docker build -f Dockerfile --tag=$IMAGE_TAG -t $IMAGE_NAME .
        - docker push $IMAGE_NAME

deploy-staging:
    stage: deploy
    image: gitlab/dind:latest
    cache: {}
    services:
        - docker:dind
    variables:
        DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    before_script:
        # add the server as a known host
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
        - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        - ssh-keyscan -H $DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    script:
        - ssh deployer@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker login -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${CI_REGISTRY}"
        # stop container, remove image.
        - ssh deployer@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker stop ${IMAGE_TAG}" || true
        - ssh deployer@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker rm ${IMAGE_TAG}" || true
        - ssh deployer@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker rmi -f ${IMAGE_NAME}" || true
        # start new container
        - ssh deployer@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker run --publish=8888:8888 -d ${IMAGE_NAME}"
    only:
        - develop
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share yaml file for pipeline ?

Comment: It seems `$IMAGE_TAG`variable is empty

Comment: @Rezwan I update my post

Comment: have u changed your config.toml file, for running docker executor with privileged flag ? https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/239

Comment: @NicolasPepinster `$IMAGE_TAG`variable is not  empty

Comment: @Rezwan how to edit gitlab-runner's config.toml file? I use gitlab.com server. I don't have acces to gitlab-runner

Comment: @Rezwan How do you modify config.toml of gitlab runner deployed via gitlab  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like variables `$IMAGE_TAG` and `$IMAGE_NAME` is empty.
You should try to add variables in deploy step, something like this

```
deploy-staging:
    stage: deploy
    image: gitlab/dind:latest
    cache: {}
    services:
        - docker:dind
    variables:
        REGISTRY_URL: registry.gitlab.com
        DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
        DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
        IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
        IMAGE_TAG: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    before_script:
        ...
```